# Why default .bashrc is set to return immediately if not running interactively?

Tags: bash, bashrc

In Ubuntu default .bashrc there's this:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

Does anyone know why that is there?  Is there something in the bashrc that is bad to run if the shell is ran non-interactively?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point of the .bashrc file is that it sets the shell up to be more convenient for interactive users. Helpful alias, pretty colors, useful prompts, common environment variables, that sort of thing.

And some of these conveniences could break non-interactive scripts. For example:

```
`alias rm='rm -i'`
```

Would not work non-interactively (thanks zwets).

Comment: What I don't understand: If bash is not started as an interactive shell, then `.bashrc` isn't read, anyway, is it? I put the line `echo ".bashrc is being sourced"` in my `.bashrc` before the `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` and then ran `bash -c "echo"` and is does not show...

Comment: Okay, I could of course do `bash -c "source ~/.bashrc"`, then it IS sourced :-)

Comment: From `man bash`: "When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc, if these files exist." So it should make one wonder why that line exists if an non-interactive shell doesn't read the file anyway. The answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/257571